# Php define() Constants Inside Namespace Clarification

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

As the title states, I would really like to clarify this. I have read a few articles and postings here on this topic, something just isn't clicking for me. I'll add I'm a bit new to Php. OK, here's what I want to understand;

```
namespace Information;
define('ROOT_URL', 'information/');
define('OFFERS_URL', ROOT_URL . 'offers/');

namespace Products;
define('ROOT_URL', 'products/');
define('OFFERS_URL', ROOT_URL . 'offers/');
```

I want the constants to be constructable, ie, build constants from base constant(s), that's why I'm using define('NAME', *value*);.

My question being, will the value of ROOT_URL yield the value relative to its' namespace? Like this;

```
$info_offers_url = \Information\OFFERS_URL;  ('information/offers/')
$prod_offers_url = \Products\OFFERS_URL;     ('products/offers/')
```

Or does define(); place ROOT_URL in a global scope, hence I shouldn't do this? Is there a better practice?

All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Quoting from the namual: `Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global.` They are not namespaced

Comment: @Mark Baker, thank you so much. How do I mark your response as the answer, and up tick you? Just want to give you some more rep points

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to define a constant in a namespace, you will need to specify the namespace in your call to define(), even if you're calling define() from within a namespace.  The following examples which I tried will make it clear.

The following code will define the constant "CONSTANTA" in the global namespace (i.e. "\CONSTANTA").

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace;
define('CONSTANTA', 'Hello A!');
?>
```

if you want to define constant for a namespace you can define like

```
<?php
namespace test;
define('test\HELLO', 'Hello world!');
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\GOODBYE', 'Goodbye cruel world!');
?>
```

Otherwise, you can use `const` to define a constant in the current namespace:

```
<?php

namespace NS;

define('C', "I am a constant");
const A = "I am a letter";

echo __NAMESPACE__, , PHP_EOL; // NS
echo namespace\A, PHP_EOL; // I am a letter
echo namespace\C, PHP_EOL; // PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'NS\C'
```

Taken from the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#90282)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is from user comments, not from the actual manual.

Comment: You can also import namespaced constants: `use const Foo\BAR`. Note the _const_.

Comment: Being able to import them also proves it is real namespacing as opposed to backslash being allowed in the name.

Comment: BTW, defining by explicitly writing out the absolute path (i.e. with '\' at the start, e.g., `define('\test\HELLO', 'Hello world!');` does not work.

Comment: Same goes for **`defined`** - they both are **namespace-*unaware*** so even when within namespace you still have specify it `defined('MyNs\Some')`, took me a while to debug this...

Answer (score 18):

Using namespaced constants is fairly easy but you must use `const` keyword.

Then you can directly call the constant using backslash `\`:

```
namespace Dummy\MyTime;
const MONTHS = 12;
const WEEKS = 52;
const DAYS = 365;


namespace Test;
use Dummy\MyTime;

$daysPerWeek = MyTime\DAYS / MyTime\WEEKS;
$daysPerMonth = MyTime\DAYS / MyTime\MONTHS;

echo "Days per week: $daysPerWeek\n"; // 7.0192307692308
echo "Days per month: $daysPerMonth\n"; // 30.416666666667
```

I think this is cleaner than using `define`.

Having said that, what you want (assign a scalar expression to a constant) will work only if you are using **PHP >= 5.6**:

```
namespace Information;
const ROOT_URL = 'information/';
const OFFERS_URL = ROOT_URL . 'offers/';

namespace Products;
const ROOT_URL = 'products/';
const OFFERS_URL = ROOT_URL . 'offers/';

namespace Test;
$info_offers_url = \Information\OFFERS_URL; // information/offers/
$prod_offers_url = \Products\OFFERS_URL;    // products/offers/
```

I hope this will help you.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: Although this answer is not directly about `define()`, it is very useful.

Comment: Not so sure about the 'must', I can define a constant for another namespace from another, and import that in a third via use. `define('Foo\BAR', 'baz');`  `use const Foo\BAR;`, Or even access these from any namespace:  `echo \Foo\BAR;`

Comment: @Progrock Thanks for clarifying, I didn't know that when I wrote my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`define()` will define constants exactly as specified.

> **Basic knowledge**: To define a constant in a namespace, you have to specify the namespace in your call to define(), even if you’re calling `define()` from within a namespace.

## The following examples will make it clear.

**The following code will define the constant `MESSAGE` in the global namespace (i.e. `\MESSAGE`).**

```
<?php
    namespace test;
    define(‘MESSAGE’, ‘Hello world!’);
?>
```

**The following code will define two constants in the “test” namespace.**

```
<?php
    namespace test;
    define(‘test\HELLO’, ‘Hello world!’);
    define(__NAMESPACE__ . ‘\GOODBYE’, ‘Goodbye cruel world!’);
?>
```

**Use it in space**

```
namespace Product;
use const test\HELLO;
```